# correct way for onClick Binding in Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a coding exercise and I was done with it and tried to play around a little.

This is the html i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script>
        function runAfter() {
            alert("HI!");
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.id = "msg";
            p.innerHTML = "TEST!";
            document.body.innerHTML += "<br />";    
            document.body.appendChild(p);
            console.log(p.innerHTML);
        };
        //window.onload=runAfter;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js file:

```
"use strict";


var Widget = {
    init: function Widget(width, height) {
        this.width = width || 50;
        this.height = height || 50;
        this.$elem = null;
    },
    render: function ($where) {
        if (this.$elem) {
            this.$elem.css({
                width: this.width + "px",
                height: this.height + "px"
            }).appendTo($where);
        }
    }
};

var Button = Object.create(Widget);

Button.config = function config(width, height, label) {
    this.init(width, height);
    this.label = label || "ClickMe";
    this.$elem = $("<button>").text(this.label);
};

Button.build = function ($where) {
    this.render($where);
    this.$elem.click(this.onClick.bind(this));
};

Button.onClick = function (evt) {
    console.log("Button '" + this.label + "' clicked!");
    this.updateMessage("Button '" + this.label + "' clicked!");
};

Button.updateMessage = function (msg) {
    var p = document.getElementById("msg");
    p.innerHTML = msg;
};

function run() {
    let $body = $(document.body);
    //create
    let btn1 = Object.create(Button);
    let btn2 = Object.create(Button);

    //initialize
    btn1.config(125, 30, "Hello");
    btn2.config(150, 40, "World");

    //build
    btn1.build($body);
    btn2.build($body);
};

$(document).ready(run);
```

if you leave `//window.onload=runAfter;` as is in html, you can see the problem in the console that comes from Button.onClick function. But the console.log works giving

```
"Button '" + this.label + "' clicked!"
```

But if you uncomment it, that function doesn't work.

What is going wrong? Is the dynamic this binding going out of scope to somewhere else ?

The `runAfter()` appends elements to dynamically generated html page from test.js.

What should happen is, the two buttons should work as expected with `console.log` and `<p>` para with `id=msg` printing out the same as `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you comment out

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>";
```

and replace it with

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Edit with explanation:

What's happening is that when you use document.body.innerHTML +=, you're taking the innerHTML as a string, adding to that string, and then replacing the entire innerHTML with the new string. So you're not adding to what's already there (the way appendChild() does), you're removing all of it and replacing it.

When you remove the buttons, the click handlers attached to them are gone. And the scripts don't run again after the innerHTML is replaced, so the click handlers are never reattached.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing out this. ill get back to you if it works for me

Comment: very nice explanation. i imagined it to work like i = i +2, usually it does.

Comment: Well it does work the same, but i+=2 is essentially var x = i+2; i=x; in that it just overwrites the value of i, doesn't actually add to it.

Comment: thanks. string operations shouldn't be done as a rule then.

Comment: .innerHTML() should be avoided, as a guideline. creating elements, setting their attributes and appending them is a safer (and sometimes more readable) alternative

Comment: got it. accessing adding childNode  to .parentNode is a better practice